# How to get List view like Vista/Windows7

Tags: visual-studio-2005, listview, c#-2.0, windows-vista, look-and-feel

Using: Visual Studio 2005, .net 2.0

Can we get the features of list view as seen in Vista/Window7 OS (file/folders details view):

1. When mouse is over  a row its highlighted.
   Problem: if i set HotTracking = true, the items are shown underlined, also mouse cursor
   changed.
2. Dragging select multiple items.
   Problem: [Multiple Select = true, FullRowSelect = true] Only the first column allows to 
   drag-select items. Other columns doesn't.
3. The nice look and feel.

How to get these facilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ObjectListView](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2) -- an open source wrapper around a WinForms ListView control. It provides many of these things and quite a few more: tooltips, drag and drop, images, tinted columns.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/fancy-screenshot3.png))</sub>